# How to reverse query selection with subquery or pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an SQL query as the following

```
SELECT Count(L.id) As Count, U.name As Name, L.action As Action
FROM tabel1 L LEFT JOIN tabel2 U ON L.uId = U.id
WHERE L.date >= '1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM' AND L.date <= '11/2/2019 12:00:00 AM' AND L.nId IN (18161, 18156, 4924, 18129, 18073, 18070, 18140, 2588, 18141, 18139, 18144, 18143, 18142, 6741, 16796, 3333, 6364, 6367, 6370, 6373, 17991, 7812, 11148, 7799, 11074) 
group by U.name, L.action
ORDER BY U.name, L.action
```

Its result as following

```
Count   Name        Action
--------------------------     
24      User 1      Create
31      User 1      Edit
252     User 2      Create
48      User 2      Edit
257     User 3      Create
29      User 3      Edit
3       User 4      Create
216     User 5      Create
287     User 5      Edit
256     User 6      Edit
9       User 6      Create
1       User 6      Delete
101     User 7      Edit
```

I need to get the result as following

```
Name      Create      Edit      Delete
--------------------------------------
User 1    24          31        0
User 2    252         48        0
User 3    257         29        0
User 4    3           0         0
User 5    216         287       0
User 6    256         9         1
User 7    0           101       0
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT U.name As Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN l.Action = 'Create' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_created,
       SUM(CASE WHEN l.Action = 'Edit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_edited,
       SUM(CASE WHEN l.Action = 'Delete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_deleted
FROM tabel1 L LEFT JOIN
     tabel2 U
     ON L.uId = U.id
WHERE L.date >= '2018-01-01' AND
      L.date <= '2019-02-11' AND
      L.nId IN (18161, 18156, 4924, 18129, 18073, 18070, 18140, 2588, 18141, 18139, 18144, 18143, 18142, 6741, 16796, 3333, 6364, 6367, 6370, 6373, 17991, 7812, 11148, 7799, 11074) 
GROUP BY U.name
ORDER BY U.name;
```

Note that I also simplified the date comparisons and introduces ISO standard formats.  However, I'm not sure if the later date is 2019-02-11 or 2019-11-02.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much.
Can you tell if Pivoting perform better?

Comment: @Ayman . . . The use of the `pivot` keyword was not originally any faster than aggregation.  I don't know if Microsoft has improved performance since it was introduced.